# Possible mistake in natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof-verification, natural-deduction

In my course notes it is stated that we can infer $\exists x\neg F$ from $\neg\forall xF$ (where $F$ is a formula) in classical logic, but not in intuitionistic logic. However, I came up with this natural deduction
$$
\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\quad}{F}\scriptstyle1}{\forall xF} \quad \begin{array}{c}\\\neg\forall xF\end{array}}{
   \cfrac{\cfrac{\bot}{\neg F} \scriptstyle1}{\exists x \neg F}
}
$$
and it seems fine and intuitionistic to me... What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot apply $\forall$-intro that way; if $Px \vdash \forall x Px$, then by $\to$-intro we get : $\vdash Px \to \forall x Px$, but this is not valid (cosider e.g. $(x=0) \to \forall x (x=0)$).

Comment: The restriction to $\forall$-intro is : the quantified variable $x$ must not be *free* in any assumption: in this case $x$ is free in the assumption $F$.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's what I was missing! Thank you :)